# custom error in Remote validation in mvc3

Tags: model-view-controller, validation, asp.net-mvc-3, attributes

I've a remote validation(with the remote attribute) and I want to display the user a different error message according to my validation logic. How I can do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the ErrorMessage attribute:

```
[Remote("UserName", "Registration", ErrorMessage = "User name is already taken!")]
```

*EDIT:*

For an idea on how to do do multiple Remote validations on the same property, check out this interesting post and the self-answer by @Fabian:

[Passing the ErrorMessage for clientside validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626739/passing-the-errormessage-for-clientside-validation/5627463)

Comment: But I've several validations in my remote , and I want each validation to have its own specific error message.

Comment: Added a link to a very similar question on here that can help you with that.  Good luck.